# Invisible Recaptcha alerting connection error

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am having some issues with Google's invisible recaptcha quite often it will show an alert box with an error message, see image below. This is quite strange because it only happens on 1 specific login page!

[image: Alert box shown in the browser]
There are 2 requests sent out.

The first one returns:

```
)]}'
["uvresp","03AA7ASh1jn5cY8cCwQ8EhZ69AiwJK4FcLCuDamXsXOrbZiTA8sAvIEmwXAOUewK3rot3o6xyJZ84z-htiHzjsHXg0WBH62ZloywRimEHEWerxcM2tykkqovigbzWPl8Q0FULGAAtC_evAE6PtQN568iK7fwKU4vgLLOBbECnWLJr4s21nOvvfuXV-E5w1mCvhSfrNQ0tBBd3xxU9cS8AKWV3gTgPtnWmK0CrOGV7mQ2_apWXuz45a0Y5G_mP8FspwdpLpd5sH0c_HUBzBeBnXnspIBpUK8JwfKELZ1Aeo1LxeAYf5WhMcR-faldLCjSzkUeb-ScWcLbp4K6bmSrKtDQ36Gk3lZsrAl4ZQuGHJlRn1tGG2KNHIt7Zi2P2lMdAoqdVz9jNt3zMRSgEbr8HeP8JAnj1ea2vCRLZ1kt8iArpqf5KRa-Fm48bzTZdgaoDngXpWjWPt6Y2MEKmEiZ9DssUNp1xbEozYYgk6kEtBamTN0R8qlPX2JZ4NZYuAavoEpyFYXeiiv602p4MiMFa4KpMKaVn4y0tvGUtHHDXwJ88yD1_3nsv_OPx8bZEVZ7Q9ZBhOxfhRZdMhPS-W8SxwF1JHtnAhYOWgOQ",1,120]
```

and the second one:

```
)]}'
["uvresp",null,null,null,0]
```

More often than not when I first click on it I am shown this message, after a second attempt it usually works. My client initially spotted the error and I assumed it was because he was accessing it from Asia, but yesterday the problem start happening to me in the UK, I assumed wrong!

I have tried different browsers and I get the same issue in all of them. Also I've cleared all my cookies etc to make sure there was nothing locally affecting it, but all these things didn't seem to help.

Next I thought it might be best to try a different site key, but again it had no affect!

Now I am completely confused because it works fine on all other pages on my site apart from that one page!